# Проблемы с запуском MySQL в XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, windows-8, xampp

При попытке запустить MySQL в XAMPP вылезает такая ошибка: 
![Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO7ae.jpg)

Также, в папке htadocs лежит файл test.php  с таким содержимым:

Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(

Настраивал всё вроде по инструкции: http://lpmj.net/3rdedition/newc2.pdf

Что у меня может не так работать?
Спасибо!

p.s. Порт 80 не занят Скайпом.

Comment: какую операционную систему вы используете?

Comment: Использую Windows 8.1, x64

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить с правами администратора

Comment: Хм..а каким образом это сделать?

Comment: правой кнопкой по исталятору и "Запустить от имени администратора" ("Run as administrator")